# Using Twilio sms-api to verify real phone numbers

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, twilio-api, sms-verification

I am building an IONIC2 app for android and iOS, the registration on my app follows these steps:

1- User installs app.

2- User Enters his details "name, email, **phone-number**, password, etc..."

3- App will send a random code to the user via **sms**.

4- App will store this code in a variable.

5- User reads the code from the **sms** and puts it into an text input.

6- App checks if code in variable == code in text input.

7- If true, user account is created and user is signed in.

Next time the user tries to sign in he will be asked to enter his username and password, **there will be no sms messages sent in this step** as I only need to verify that the phone number is real.

Is this wrong for some reason? and is there a better way to do it?

The code I will be using is simply typescript and html (for ionic2) using angular2, the below code is written in jquery which I will change if i am on the right track.

I should add, there will be no server for this sms verification service, only javascript and the twilio api.

**Will anyone be able to read my SID and KEY? as it is an app and not a static web page**

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        // Your Twilio credentials

        var SID = "MY-SID-HERE";
        var Key = "MY-KEY-HERE";
        var random_code_in_sms = "123456"; // generated randomly


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + SID + '/Messages',
            data: {
                "To": "+123456789",
                "From": "+987654321",
                "Body": "Hello World"
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(SID + ':' + Key));
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(1);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use Twilio's [Authy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy/authy-phone-verification-api) api instead of trying to build your own solution on the back of their SMS api.

It basically already does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Doesnt that require a backend? Everything i have read said it required a server of some kind

Comment: No, that's the whole point. Twilio provides the back end. There are several options for integration, but in it's most simple form you make an HTTP  POST to Twilio with users phone number, Twilio generates a code and sends it to them via SMS, user enters code into your app, you make an HTTP GET request with the users phone number and code and Twilios response tells you if it's correct or not.

Comment: Thanks i am working on it now!!! I will update your post as answered, thank you again